# How To Copy Formulas Only In Google Sheets (without values or formatting) in few steps?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, copy-paste

I've found a way to copy formulas only in Google Sheets through `Search and Replace` `Ctrl` + `H` feature workaround as follows:

**STEP 1:**

**Cells with Formulas to be copied**
[image: Cells with Formulas to be copied]

**STEP 2:**

**Press `Ctrl` + `H` and *Tick Also search within formulas***
[image: Press Ctrl + H and Tick Also search within formulas]

**STEP 3:**

**Copy Formulas (formulas only are copied)**
[image: Copy Formulas (formulas only are copied)]

**STEP 4:**

**Select a destination cell/range and paste the clipboard content**
[image: Select a destination cell/range and paste the clipboard content]

**STEP 5:**

**Result: Formulas only are pasted**
[image: Result: Formulas only are pasted]

Please share any way you know to do it with less steps.
Thanks a lot for your help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, I don't understand your need to use `ctrl+h` to do this. You could've just used `ctrl+c` and `ctrl+v`, since you are copying the cell content, which is the formula. I know it will also copy the cell's formatting, but if it's a previously blank cell, there should be no problem.

A fast way to do it is copying the range of cells you want to copy the formulas from, and the `right click` - `special paste` - `past only the formula`.

[image: Special Paste]

~Sorry for the portuguese menu. The option should be in the same spot, though.~

The only workaround you *could* need is copying the actual values given by the formula on these cells, and for that Sheets also has a keyboard shortcut: `ctrl+shift+v`, which is a special paste case, which pastes only the results, not the formula.

So unless you're lacking one or more of those keys, you should be fine. If you do, a mere select range - right click - copy - paste would do the trick. No need for extra long steps.

---

Now, if what you're trying to accomplish is copying the formula and paste it as a string, you can use the `=FORMULATEXT([CELL])`.

[image: FormulaText()]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rodrigo Biffi. You rock! The `=FORMULATEXT([CELL])` did it. I needed the formula as `input` to copy and paste in another text editor (like sublime text) to quickly edit many formulas at once and then paste them back (edited) into google sheet.  The issue with the `right click > paste special > paste formula only`  method is that it returns the formula `output` when pasting directly into google sheet or an external editor — so your  `=FORMULATEXT([CELL])` method is the quicker way to go. Thanks again. Be well!

Comment: `Paste Special` → `Formulas only` will still not 1 to 1 copy the formula cell references. It updates to new cells.

Comment: I just learned about FORMULATEXT(). Thanks, @Rodrigo Biffi, for the reminder! Worked perfectly.